# How do I map the device details such as \Device\Harddisk1\DR1 in the event log to a drive letter such as C:?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, event-log

Using the event viewer, I can see that the event log has entries such as "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk1\DR1." and "The driver detected a controller error on \Device\Harddisk1\DR7.".

Using VC++ code, I want to translate this device path (e.g. \Device\Harddisk1\DR1) to a drive letter such as C: wherever applicable (I understand that not all the devices will map to a drive letter).

Using **FindFirstVolume** and **FindNextVolume** I am able to loop through all the volumes and for each, I am using **QueryDosDevice** to get the device name and **GetVolumePathNamesForVolumeName** to get the drive letter.

The problem I am having is that when I use the above method to get the device names, I end up with device names such as "\Device\HarddiskVolume3", "\Device\HarddiskVolume2", etc.
I do get these mapped to the drive letters. However, I am not sure how these map to the device name format I see in the event log entry.

So, in summary, my question is:
How do I map the device name format "**\Device\HarddiskVolume%d**" to the format "**\Device\Harddisk%d\DR%d**" where each %d is a number.

Comment: A disk often has multiple volumes.  And a volume can span multiple drives.  Also sounds like a RAID with that many drives.  So there is just no one-to-one mapping.

Comment: Related question: SuperUser, 2013-01-19: [*Which drive is \Device\Harddisk1\DR1?*](https://superuser.com/questions/538574/which-drive-is-device-harddisk1-dr1/)

Answer (score 5):

This isn't C++ code, but two applications written in C++ show this information, at least to check your results.  I don't believe the source of either application is readily available.

1. [NirSoft's DriveLetterView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/drive_letter_view.html) matches drive letter to `\Device\HarddiskVolume%d` in the `Drive Letter` and `Device Path` columns.

[image: NirSoft's DriveLetterView]

2. [SysInternals' WinObj](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896657.aspx) matches drive letter to `\Device\HarddiskVolume%d` and `\Device\Harddisk%d\DR%d` to `PhysicalDrive%d`.

[image: WinObj example]

Comment: Thanks, but still no clues for which drive letter is \Device\Harddisk1\DR1 in my laptop, any suggestion?

Comment: @GangYIN It could be so that you may not have even formatted that partition. Perhaps check the windows disk utility (create and format disk partitions). If you see an unallocated partition, it is not a volume and WMI based tools like WinObj will typically show it as `\Device\Harddisk2\DR2`. It probably points to one of the many 'hidden' partitions on modern laptops. Vendors use it for EFI, device recovery etc

Answer (score 0):

Updating @Dan-H's answer:

### DriveLetterView

[NirSoft DriveLetterView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/drive_letter_view.html) doesn't show the DRnumber, as in `\Device\Harddisk1\DR1`

But it does show the `\Device\HarddiskVolumeN` and the `\PhysicalDriveN` and the `X:\` drive letter

The `\Device\HarddiskN`  number and the `\PhysicalDriveN` number are the same.

So knowing that, you can take the `\Device\HarddiskN` number from `\Device\HarddiskN\DRx` and look at the corresponding `\PhysicalDriveN` in DriveLetterView and then look at the corresponding `X:\` drive letter.

[image: DriveLetterView showing DRx, PhysicalDriveN and VolumeV]

### WinOjb

[WinObj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/winobj) has had some improvements since 2014. It's now up to v3.10 as of 07/20/2021.

Note, have to run as administrator, otherwise it doesn't show as much info.

Also note, sorting the columns is incredibly helpful in finding information. As is the new search.

`GLOBAL??` is the most useful in the left nav pane.

Sorting `GLOBAL??` by column `Symbolic Link Target` you can map

- `\Device\HarddiskN\DRx`
- to `\PhysicalDriveN`
- to `Harddisk1Partition1`
- to `\Device\HarddiskVolumeN`
- to `X:\` drive letter

[image: WinObj showing \DeviceHarddiskN\DRx \VolumeV and X:\ drive letter]

You can also use WinObj search to find these mappings.

The volume numbers do not match command line tool `diskpart`; that has its own volume numbering scheme. But the `\PhysicalDriveN` and `HarddiskN` appear to match `diskpart` numbering (but I'd confirm before relying on it).